# Why does retrieving stored data cost so much compared to using calldata in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, bytes, calldata

I have a function that I need to pass an arbitrary length array of addresses to. In remix, just calling a function that has an `address[]` costs around 30k gas for an array of 5 addresses:

```
function fun(address[] calldata addresses) external returns (address[] memory) {
    return addresses;
}
```

The addresses that I want to call are of a finite set of about 2000 addresses, but it could be any of those addresses when I call my function, so I thought that I could store them in a mapping of `uint=>address` and call my function with an array of uint16's that I can then look up the addresses with (that I previously stored). Theoretically this should be much cheaper because the calldata is way smaller:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.17;

contract StoreIDToAddress {
    
    mapping(uint => address) public numToAddress;

    
    function getAddresses(uint16[] calldata  _IDs) external view returns (address[] memory) {
        address[] memory arr = new address[](_IDs.length);
        
        for (uint i; i < _IDs.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = numToAddress[_IDs[i]];
        }
        
        return arr;
    }

    // Other functions to initialize numToAddress etc
}
```

`getAddresses` costs 29378 gas with an input of `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.
This alone makes it no cheaper than just including the addresses themselves in the calldata, and when I tested with a 2nd contract that takes in an `uint16[]` and passes it to `getAddresses` it costs 34196 gas:

```
    function testUint16Arr3(uint16[] calldata _arr) external returns (address[] memory) {
        return storeIDToAddress.getAddresses(_arr);
    }
```

Using `bytes` and decoding that in to a `uint16` to call `getAddresses` is 35095 gas.

So my question is, why does `getAddresses` cost so much gas when (AFAIK) the biggest operation is 5 x SLOAD = 1000 gas? How can I reduce the gas cost of getting addresses in to my functions?

Comment: The transaction itself costs a minimum of 21000, and your gas-measurement method probably doesn't take that into account. Add `uint256 public gasUsed` in your contract, then add `uint256 gasLeft = gasleft();` at the beginning of your function, and then add `gasUsed = gasLeft - gasleft();` at the end of your function. Then, after calling your function from the offchain, call `gasUsed()` in order to check how much gas the function really used.

Comment: Note that they might have renamed `gasleft()` in solc 0.4.x to `gasLeft()` in solc 0.5.x, so you might need to use different names in my example above, depending on your solc version.

Comment: Yes you're right, and I had been using `gasleft()` for 0.5.x but I was still surprised at the ~9k+ of gas attributed to dealing with `storage` variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Istanbul](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1679) hardfork included [EIP-1884](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1884), which (among other repricings) repriced SLOAD from 200 to 800 gas. That means loading 5 addresses from storage will cost 4000 gas, not including any overhead. The Istanbul hardfork also included [EIP-2028](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2028), which lowered the cost of non-zero calldata bytes from 68 to 16. These two EIPS are what cause the huge difference in gas costs from what you are expecting.

Also as @goodvibration mentioned in a comment, there is an inbuilt cost of 21000 gas with all transactions. This is the base cost, and any contract interaction you do is on-top of this amount.

Comment: I see, thank you.
I suppose this is to help prevent further bloat of the state?